# What is the meaning of "one must of necessity"?

Tags: meaning

I have read this sentence. But, I can not understand the meaning of "one must of necessity".

> To be a great leader and so always master of the situation, one must of necessity have been a great thinker in action.

Can any one explain it?

Comment: That's a poorly written sentence: "so always master of the situation"...must of necessity is also a redundancy. I think the writer is trying to say great leaders must be great thinkers. Ugh. I would look for better texts to read if you have the option.

Comment: @lonstar That's appears to be a quote by somebody named James Thomas (which one?) on the subject of leadership. The complete quote reads: "To be a great leader and so always master of the situation, one must of necessity have been a great thinker in action. An eagle was never yet hatched from a goose's egg."

Comment: An emphatic -1. When asking questions like this (asking for the meaning of a sentence), it's imperative to tell _where_ you found the sentence.  Include a link, or at least include the whole paragraph of the source. **Context is everything.** I could ask what this sentence means: [_Lance shot the model._](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lISKr.png) It can mean a range of things, depending on if Lance is a photographer, a gunman, or a nurse in an immunization clinic; depending on if the _model_ refers to a woman wearing fashion, or a model of, say, a car, an airplane, a molecule, or the solar system.

Comment: Yep, I gave that a little too cursory reading. Still not sure what to do with "thinker in action". And +1 to JR's comment.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to a comment, OP's example is a perfectly reasonable sentence. It's attributed to [James Thomas Fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Thomas_Fields), apparently first published 1900 by [Modern eloquence](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22necessity%20have%20been%20a%20great%20thinker%20in%20action%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22must%20of%20necessity%20have%20been%20a%20great%20thinker%20in%20action%22&oq=%22must%20of%20necessity%20have%20been%20a%20great%20thinker%20in%20action%22&gs_l=serp.3...99418.101736.0.102231.8.8.0.0.0.1.101.549.7j1.8.0...0.0...1c.DAvzZpi9xco&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=644001cab0275ea4&biw=1306&bih=905) (*they* thought it was okay!).

The component *of necessity* is just an intensifier of *must* - some might say it's tautological, but I see nothing wrong with that (or [15,000 more instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hay%20is%20for%20horses%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:1996&lr=lang_en#hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1990,cd_max:1996,lr%3alang_1en&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22must%20of%20necessity%22&oq=%22must%20of%20necessity%22&gs_l=serp.3...27456762.27460760.0.27461484.17.17.0.0.0.1.163.1158.15j2.17.0...0.0...1c.-KvMIgfQbrU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=32702e2e2cdf27bc&biw=1300&bih=905) of *"must of necessity"* in Google Books).

The sentence says that a great leader is always master of the situation - that's why *"so"* links the two descriptions, because the first implies/entails/necessitates the second. But it also says you *definitely can't* be a great leader unless you've been a "great thinker in action".

Comment: How does the nuance change when "one must of necessity" is replaced with "one must _out_ of necessity"?

Comment: @coleopterist: In some contexts, the extra word doesn't make any difference. Here, *"of necessity"* means something like *"it's an inherent relationship that automatically holds true"*, whereas *"**out** of necessity"* invariably implies that someone *is forced* (often against their will) to do something.

Comment: That is well put. Cheers :)

Comment: @coleopterist: Cheers for *your* comment on the question! I knew it was a perfectly reasonable sentence (I only really answered to redress lonstar's questionable comment), but I was amused to see that the earliest citation I could find was *"Modern Eloquence!"*

Comment: Ah :) Going by the excerpt, it appears that the James Thomas in the attribution is actually James Thomas Fields ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Thomas_Fields ), a man with an impressive array of friends!

Comment: @coleopterist: Enough already! I only meant it was *perfectly reasonable* in the grammatical sense. Semantically/philosophically, I think it's fatuous pontification, so I don't need to know what other "gems" the man may have squeezed out. His surname doesn't seem to have gone down in history, given it's rarely in the attributions on the net, so he's not exactly Churchill when it comes to pithy words of wisdom for all to remember!

Comment: lol! In that case, I will refrain from noting that he also appears to be the dedicatee of an insipid poem by Longfellow. This one: http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Auf_Wiedersehen ;)

Comment: “of necessity” == “necessarily”

Answer (score 3):

The term ***must*** can mean you are under an obligation imposed by some authority:

"You ***must*** go to school!"

"Sez who?"

In the alternative, it can mean that something need be done because of the intrinsic nature of the situation:

"To set an object in motion, you ***must*** introduce an outside force."

In the quoted sentence, *of necessity* suggests it is the latter type of ***must***.

Answer (score 1):

"One must of necessity..." = "It is necessary that one..."

Comment: Erm... you might as well say *One must...* = *One has to of necessity...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers fair enough; have updated to reflect the emphasis you describe (in your excellent already+1 answer) suggested by "of necessity."

Comment: +1 for yours too, now it's been changed to something that does meaningfully recast the original in a way that might be easier for a non-native speaker to grasp.